# Simulink - too much current is drawing from batteries

Tags: bms, simulink, cell-balancing

I am trying to simulate an active cell balancing circuit shown in the figure. However I have some problems. If I only turn on and of the switches I get normal,calculated current passing through inductor, but when I try to balance one of the cells very high current passes through inductor.

What part is wrong, why that much current passes? [image: rewithout balancingreenter image description hereference]
[![with balancing][3]][3]

[image: without balancing]

Comment: with balancing https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Eu7C.png

Comment: if you put a voltage across an inductor, the current changes with time. How are you timing the switch operation?

Comment: @Neil_UK frequency is 9800 Hz and duty cycle is 50 percent for both switches. Normally there should be another switches but in the paper those switches always on and that is why I just connected them directly. Total voltage is 58.8 in full charge.

Comment: OK, so what's the value of the inductor? What's its saturation current?

Comment: "... but in the paper ..." If you're working off of a paper or any other external source, always **include a citation**; if the paper is online, include a link, too.  If the source is truly paper or if it's behind a paywall, try to figure out if there's a few lines of relevant text and **quote the paper**.  Please _edit your question_ with a citation.

Comment: While you're editing, tell us where your pictures came from, how you've decided to drive the switches, what you're doing when you "only turn on and off the switches" and what you're doing when you "try to balance one of the cells".  Waveforms or control rules would be nice.  I assume that one picture came from this uncited paper, and the other is your simulink -- but we don't know that.  You may also wish to explain why, in the top diagram, the action is on one cell, while in the bottom one it is across three.